# /usr/bin/time giving its output in one single line

Tags: bash, shell, time, ubuntu-16.04

I may have a locale problem or something similar, because whenever I run /usr/bin/time it gives me the output as a single line, difficult to interpret :

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1756maxresident)k
```

The above comes from echo with no parameters, but it's the case with all commands.

Comment: Check `man time`, section on formatting. Also, try portability format with `time -p` and verbose with `time -v`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the -v option. I need the memory usage so the bultin time was not an option even if the display is right.

Comment: Have you tried using `/usr/bin/time echo 2>&1 | xargs -n 1`? Note that time outputs on `stderr`, so you have to redirect it to `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the 'POSIX' style:

```bash
$ /usr/bin/time -p ls
```

or integrated `time` in `bash`/`zsh`/`fish`...

```bash
$ time ls
```

or use your style, by creating a var called `TIME` or in some system called  `TIMEFORMAT`

```bash
$ export TIME="%E"
$ /usr/bin/time ls
```